# I need to restrict emails from user initialized using Cc Email Address

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

how do I  restrict emails from CC Email Address in user initialised I have selected target dataextension in Edit Recipients but i dont need to send to emails for two emails from target dataextension and restrict emails using CC Email Address i wrote amp script code in CC Email Address for restrict emails this is my code
CCPERSONPEM this fields from dataextension this field contains value

```
%%[IF [CCPERSONPEM] !="ravibics555@gmail.com" then ]%%   
   ravibics555@gmail.com, 
%%[ELSEIF [CCPERSONPEM] !="ravibics560@gmail.com" then]%%  
   ravibics560@gmail.com 
%%[ELSE]%% 
   %%Email%% 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be something similar to:

```
%%[IF @FieldName == "EmailToRestrict-One@email.com" THEN]%% 
"ReplacementEmail-One@email.com"
[ELSEIF @FieldName == "EmailToRestrict-Two@email.com" THEN]%% "ReplacementEmail-Two@email.com"
[ELSEIF @FieldName != "EmailToRestrict-One@email.com" OR EmailToRestrict-Two@email.com" THEN]%% %%EmailField%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```